# Unable to setup Aerospike single node cluster due to DISALLOW MIGRATIONS

Tags: aerospike, aerospike-ce

Getting below logs while setting up aerospike. It says DISALLOW MIGRATION. Although as per doc, [it says](https://docs.aerospike.com/reference/metrics#migrate_allowed) that migrations are disallowed while rebalance is happening. But since it is a newly setup single node cluster, it should not need rebalance.I am able to run aql command but insert command gives (11) AEROSPIKE_ERR_CLUSTER.
AE version: 3.12.0

```
Aug 28 2022 00:12:50 GMT+0530: INFO (paxos): (paxos.c:2323) Sent partition sync request to node bb9c93e220a0102
Aug 28 2022 00:12:51 GMT+0530: INFO (paxos): (paxos.c:2790) Self(bb95ccd200a0102) add from Principal bb9c93e220a0102
Aug 28 2022 00:12:51 GMT+0530: INFO (paxos): (paxos.c:2825) {1661625765} sending prepare_ack to bb9c93e220a0102
Aug 28 2022 00:12:51 GMT+0530: INFO (paxos): (paxos.c:2790) Self(bb95ccd200a0102) add from Principal bb9c93e220a0102
Aug 28 2022 00:12:51 GMT+0530: INFO (paxos): (paxos.c:2790) Self(bb95ccd200a0102) add from Principal bb9c93e220a0102
Aug 28 2022 00:12:51 GMT+0530: INFO (partition): (partition_balance.c:143) DISALLOW MIGRATIONS
Aug 28 2022 00:12:51 GMT+0530: INFO (paxos): (paxos.c:153) cluster_key set to 0x32b75076a5b4a8f3
Aug 28 2022 00:12:51 GMT+0530: INFO (paxos): (paxos.c:3099) SUCCESSION [1661625771]@bb9c93e220a0102*: bb9c93e220a0102 bb9bd1f210a0102 bb99ca1200a0102 bb99c9e220a0102 bb95ccd200a0102 bb90e3a200a0102
Aug 28 2022 00:12:51 GMT+0530: INFO (paxos): (paxos.c:3110) node bb9c93e220a0102 is now principal pro tempore
Aug 28 2022 00:12:51 GMT+0530: INFO (paxos): (paxos.c:2323) Sent partition sync request to node bb9c93e220a0102
Aug 28 2022 00:12:51 GMT+0530: INFO (drv_ssd): (drv_ssd.c:2117) {idempotency} /grid/1/aerospike/idempotency.dat: used-bytes 0 free-wblocks 21503 write-q 0 write (0,0.0) defrag-q 0 defrag-read (0,0.0) defrag-write (0,0.0)
Aug 28 2022 00:12:52 GMT+0530: INFO (drv_ssd): (drv_ssd.c:2117) {exclusion} /grid/1/aerospike/exclusion.dat: used-bytes 0 free-wblocks 102399 write-q 0 write (0,0.0) defrag-q 0 defrag-read (0,0.0) defrag-write (0,0.0)
Aug 28 2022 00:12:52 GMT+0530: INFO (drv_ssd): (drv_ssd.c:2117) {mps} /grid/1/aerospike/mps.dat: used-bytes 0 free-wblocks 40959 write-q 0 write (0,0.0) defrag-q 0 defrag-read (0,0.0) defrag-write (0,0.0)
Aug 28 2022 00:12:52 GMT+0530: INFO (paxos): (paxos.c:2630) as_paxos_retransmit_check: node bb95ccd200a0102 retransmitting partition sync request to principal bb9c93e220a0102 ...
Aug 28 2022 00:12:52 GMT+0530: INFO (paxos): (paxos.c:2323) Sent partition sync request to node bb9c93e220a0102
```

Comment: Why are you using Aerospike 3.12? That is over 5 years old.

Comment: From the logs, there is at least one other node in the network (see the two distinct node-ids). Edit your convif and change the hb configuration to mesh and don't include any seeds.